# Nested Decoratee with a Factory in between

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

We've got a hierarchy of 3 decoratees implementing an interface like:

```
public interface IRetrieve
{
    List<Widget> Retrieve(List<long> ids);
}
```

We are attempting to use the following pattern:

- RetrieveBatcher : IRetriever // batch up calls into smaller sizes
- RetrieveTimer : IRetriever // ensure the retrieval is timed out after an interval
- RetrieveCore : IRetriever // perform the actual retrieve

The runtime code looks something like this:

**RetrieveBatcher (decorator)**

```
class RetrieveBatcher : IRetriever
{
    Func<IRetriever> _decoratee;

    public RetrieveBatcher(Func<IRetriever> decoratee)
    {
        _decoratee = decoratee;
    }

    public List<Widget> Retrieve(List<long> ids) {
        return ids
           .Batch(10)
           .AsParallel()
           .SelectMany(b => _decoratee().Retrieve(b))
           .ToList();    
    }
}
```

**RetrieveTimer (decorator)**

```
class RetrieveTimer : IRetriever
{
    private readonly IRetriever _retriever;
    private const int timeout = 5;

    public class RetrieveTimer(IRetriever retriever) : IRetriever
    {
        // This needs to be the "core" retriever
        _retriever = retriever;
    }

    public List<Widget> Retrieve(List<long> ids) {
        var task = Task.Run(() => 
            {
                return _retriever.Retrieve(ids);
            }
        );
        if (task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout)))
        {
            return task.Result;
        }
        else
        {
            // handle "timer exceeded" fallout
            throw new Exception("timer exceeded");
        }
    }
}
```

**RetrieveCore**

```
class RetrieveCore : IRetriever {
    public List<Widget> Retrieve(List<long> ids) 
    {
        // Do something
        return new List<Widget>();
    }    
}
```

I'm wrestling with the registration, because this isn't a straightforward decorator hierarchy.  Instead, we've got:

- RetrieveBatcher (Decorator), which uses:
- RetrieveTimer (Factory), which is itself a decorator of:
- RetrieveCore - the actual retriever

We've had to "cheat" with SimpleInjector, along the lines of:

```
// outermost layer:
container.Register<IRetriever, RetrieveBatcher>();

// Function (Factory) that returns "Timed" utility
// See: http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#register-factory-delegates
// This registers the Func<> as the singleton, not the RetrieveTimer instance
container.RegisterSingleton<Func<IRetriever>>(
    () => new RetrieveTimer(new RetrieveCore()));
```

This works, but the actual "new RetrieveCore()" dependency seems less than ideal.

Is there some way we can configure SimpleInjector to handle this situation correctly?

Comment: I updated your question, and added the missing constructor to the ReceiveBatcher decorator. Please verify whether this is the correct code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no reason why regular `RegisterDecorator` calls wouldn't solve your problem:

```
container.Register<IRetriever, RetrieveCore>();
container.RegisterDecorator<IRetriever, RetrieveTimer>();
container.RegisterDecorator<IRetriever, RetrieveBatcher>();
```

This results in the following object graph when `IRetriever` is resolved:

```
new RetrieveBatcher(() => new RetrieveTimer(new RetrieveCore()));
```

Comment: This works!  It appears that even though my code is injecting Func<IRetriever>, and I only register IRetriever (and 2 decorators), SimpleInjector is able to correctly inject the Func<IRetriever>.  Very nice!

Comment: That's why Simple Injector is awesome. You're welcome :)